# Text from first <td> (onclick to a row)

Tags: javascript, onclick

How to get the text of the first cell when you click on a table row ?

Table like this:

```
<table id="tableID">
       <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                echo '<tr class="alt">
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['password'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['phone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
              </tr>';
            }
       ?>
```

And javascript function:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
                // what i need to do there????
            };
        }
}
```

Comment: `this.cells[0].innerHTML`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first cell with `this.cells[0]` and the text inside with `innerHTML`:

```
table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.cells[0].innerHTML);             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML = 42;
```

Take a look at that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IceWave/6u8hj7u2/1/